# How to create a new list from another in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, arraylist, collections

In Java we can create a new list from another like this:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add(1)
list1.add(-10)
list1.add(12)
list1.add(37)

List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
```

how can we achieve the same result as above in Kotlin using `listOf()` or `mutableListOf()?`

Comment: What do you want `list2` to contain? In the code sample above, it is empty.

Comment: Sorry. list2 should contain list1, I've edited the question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`.toList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-list.html) and [`.toMutableList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-list.html) extensions to copy a container (an array, a collection, a sequence) into a new list:

```
val list1 = listOf(1, -10, 12, 37)

val list2 = list1.toList()
val mutableList2 = list2.toMutableList()
```